# Task.WaitAll and cancelled tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have two ContinueWith for a task. The first one handles the case when the task is finished successfully and the second one for the case when it fails.
Then I wait till one of them is finished.
The sample code is below:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Console.WriteLine("Task is finished"); });
var success = task.ContinueWith(
    t => Console.WriteLine("Success")
    , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
    );
var failed = task.ContinueWith(
    t => Console.WriteLine("Failed")
    , TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion
    );

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(success, failed);
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
}
```

My question is, is it possible to rewrite it to avoid TaskCanceledException raising?

Comment: `WaitAll` doesn't wait till one is finished, that would be `WaitAny`.

Comment: WaitAny will pass through at the moment when one of them is cancelled without waiting when actual actions will be done

Comment: Yes, I was just correcting the terminology for when passers-by read this and think `WaitAll` waits for one to finish and not the other.

Comment: Can both failed and success throw? Or should only fail throw?

Comment: Changing that `WaitAll` to a `WhenAll` and simply ignoring the task of the `WhenAll` will not propagate the `TaskCanceledException`.

Comment: But then they go unhandled. Im assuming he wants his exceptions handled.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The question is can try/catch be avoided and exceptions not raised. If it is just a task cancellation exception and nothing else then this might be fine.

Comment: @Adam But that way, **any** exception which might occur would go unnoticed.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Indeed. In that case it is counter to what is being asked. If that were such a large concern, catching exceptions and filtering out cancellation would be the route to go. I'm actually waiting patiently for the correct answer here as my experience with it is limited.

Comment: I have edited the post a little bit to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to have handlers for both success and failure, I don't see much reason to have them in separate `ContinueWith()` calls. One call, that will happen always should be enough:

```
var continuation = task.ContinueWith(
    t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
            Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
    });

continuation.Wait();
```

Assuming `task` will never be canceled, this will behave pretty much the same as your original code.

Comment: thanks svick, usually I am using the approach you've described. But sometimes there are reasons why it will be better to have two different `ContinueWith`, for example when the "success" `ContinueWith` should have its own `ContinueWith` our there are different schedulers for "success" and "failed" `ContinueWith`